# Need Custom WordPress Form to Send All Fields in Body of Email

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have been looking for an HTML5 compliant and accessible form plugin for a site, but there is not one out there so I ended up coding one myself (from info I have found here). It works, but I want to be able to have all fields sent in the body of the email upon submission. This just sends the message from the textarea. I'm not an expert in PHP so the answer isn't obvious to me. I appreciate any help!!

```html
<pre>
<?php
function html_form_code() 
{
 ?>

 <form action="<?php esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="post">
   <label for="url" class="hidden">URL</label>
     <input type="url" name="url" id="url" class="hidden" />
   <label for="cf-name">Name*</label>
     <input type="text" name="cf-name" id="cf-name" placeholder="Name" pattern="[^.]*" value="<?php isset($_POST['cf-name']) ? esc_attr($_POST['cf-name']) : ''; ?>" />
   <label for="cf-email">Email*</label>
     <input type="email" name="cf-email" id="cf-email" placeholder="Example: name@domain.com" value="<?php isset($_POST['cf-email']) ? esc_attr($_POST['cf-email']) : ''; ?>" />
   <label for="cf-phone">Phone</label>
     <input type="tel" name="cf-phone" id="cf-phone" placeholder="123-456-7890" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" />
   <label for="cf-message">How Can We Help You?*</label>
     <textarea rows="4" name="cf-message" id="cf-message" placeholder="Your Message"><?php isset($_POST['cf-message']) ? esc_attr($_POST['cf-message']) : ''; ?></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="SEND"/>
 </form>

 <?php
}

// Form validation
function my_validate_form()
{
     $errors = new WP_Error();

     if (isset($_POST[ 'url' ]) && $_POST[ 'url' ] !== '') {
         $errors->add('cheater', 'Ignore this text box. It is used to detect spammers. If you enter anything into it, your message will not be sent.');
     }

     if (isset($_POST[ 'cf-name' ]) && $_POST[ 'cf-name' ] == '') {
         $errors->add('name_error', 'Please tell us your name.');
     }

     if (isset($_POST[ 'cf-email' ]) && $_POST[ 'cf-email' ] == '') {
         $errors->add('email_error', 'Please fill in a valid email.');
     }

     if (isset($_POST[ 'cf-message' ]) && $_POST[ 'cf-message' ] == '') {
         $errors->add('message_error', 'Please send us a message.');
     }
    return $errors;
}


 // Form delivery
function deliver_mail($args = array())
{

  $defaults = array(
    'name' => '',
    'email' => '',
    'phone' => '',
    'to' => get_option('admin_email'), // can change this to an email address
  );

     $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
     $headers = "From: {$args['name']}  <{$args['email']}>"."\r\n";
     $subject = "Website Inquiry";

  // Send email returns true on success, false otherwise
 if (wp_mail($args['to'], $subject, $args['message'], $headers)) {
      return;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}

// Form Sanitize
function my_sanitize_field($input)
{
    return trim(stripslashes(sanitize_text_field($input)));
}

// Success Message
function my_form_message()
{
    global $errors;
    if (is_wp_error($errors) && empty($errors->errors)) {
        echo '<div class="cf-success">';
        echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us '.$_POST['cf-name'].', we will be in touch with you soon.</p>';
        echo '</div>';

    //Empty $_POST because we already sent email
    $_POST = '';
    } else {
        if (is_wp_error($errors) && !empty($errors->errors)) {
            $error_messages = $errors->get_error_messages();
            foreach ($error_messages as $k => $message) {
                echo '<div class="cf-error '.$k.'">';
                echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}



// Form shortcode
add_shortcode('gr_contact_form', 'cf_shortcode');
function cf_shortcode()
{
    ob_start();

    my_form_message();
    html_form_code();

    return ob_get_clean();
}

// Error validation
add_action('init', 'my_cf_form');
function my_cf_form()
{
    if (isset($_POST['cf-submitted'])) {
        global $errors;
        $errors = my_validate_form();
        if (empty($errors->errors)) {
            $args = array(
         'name' => my_sanitize_field($_POST['cf-name']),
         'email' => my_sanitize_field($_POST['cf-email']),
         'message' => my_sanitize_field($_POST['cf-message']),
       );
            deliver_mail($args);
        } else {
            return $errors;
        }
    }
}
?>
</pre>
```

Comment: `'message' => my_sanitize_field($_POST['cf-message'])` is what creates the message body.  You can see it only contains a sanitized copy of the value submitted from the cf-message text area.  You'd need to expand it to include the sanitized contents from the other fields.  I do feel like you're reinventing the wheel though.  There are plugins like Contact Form 7 which are well documented and do a great job with mail forms and function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin. What would the syntax be to expand it to other fields? That's where I'm stuck. As for other plugins, I've installed and tested just about every one of them and none of them (expect two that have iffy support) allow me to use my own html.